# disable scrolling on webpage and allow it only on page sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working onepage website, what i'm trying to do is to disable scorlling on webpage and only and make transitions between sections using the navbar links to id. for that i have use this jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-scrollTo').on('click', function() { 
        var page = $(this).attr('href'); 
        var speed = 1000;
        $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: $(page).offset().top }, speed );
        return false;
    });
});
```

and this on CSS

```
html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden}
```

everything work fine except one issue is that when im in a specific section that have a big content i can't scroll within in, what im trying to figure out is: how to enable scrolling within section itself without scrolling all the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, what you can do in this case is add an `overflow-y:scroll` to the wrapping div of the content you wish to be scrollable.

For example, say we have a div#test with some content:

```
<div id="test">
   ... Some content
</div>
```

We can then simply apply the styles:

```
#test {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #ff1000;
}
```

Here is it in action: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRYERR

Comment: thank you for your answer but i have tried that before and it didnt work for me, it only show the scroll bar but it dont really scroll beside its ugly, im looking for something in jquery for a slim scroll bar

Comment: For this to work, you'll need to ensure that the div itself is bounded at some height (i.e. set a height on it) so the content actually overflows. Also, for the custom scrollbar, there are a number of libraries you could use to change the look of it, such as [this](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar)

Answer (score 1):

You can add css to your div :-

```
yourDiv:hover { overflow: auto; height:desired height }
```